# URL Profile ID doesn't match (match.params.id) and isnt dispalyed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So whenever I clicked the View Profile Link:

```
<Link to={`/profile/${_id}`} className="btn btn-primary">
                View Profile
 </Link>
```

It shows in the URL the User ID of the Profile, which is Good. But I get a blank page and my navbar and div doesn't show from the below code:

```
const Profile = ({ getProfileById, profile: { profile, loading }, auth, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(match.params.id);
  }, [getProfileById]);

  return <div>profile</div>;
}
```

In my console, I also do get "Line 10:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'getProfileById' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" but IDK if it does anything. This is what my app.js looks like, and please help!

App.js:

```
<Route path='/profiles' element={<Profiles/>} /> 
<Route path='/profile/:id' element={<Profile/>} />
```

This below is in my actions/profile.js file:

```
// Get profile by ID
export const getProfileById = userId => async dispatch => {

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/profile/user/${userId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this,

```
 <Route path='/profile/:id' element={<Profile/>} />
```

do this,

```
<Route path='/profile/:id' component={Profile} />
```

Comment: im on version 6 of react router so i dont think that would work